# Inclusion and exclusion principal in java

Tags: java, c++, logic, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Hi I want  to code inclusion and exclusion principal in Java.
I want to code for this problem

Given N prime numbers and a number M, find out how many numbers from 1 to M are divisible by any of the N given prime numbers.

```
 The number of integers between 1 and 500 (both inclusive) that are divisible by 3 or 5 or 7 is

 P(3 U 5 U 7) = P(3) + P(5) + P(7) - P(3X5) - P(5X7)- P(3X7)+ P(3X5X7)

 P(3) = 500/3 = 166.66 Take 166 ,
 P(5) = 500/5 = 100 ,
 P(7) = 500/7 = 71.42 Take 71,
 P(3X5) = p(15) = 500/15 = 33.33 Take 33 ,
 P(7X5) = p(35) = 500/35 = 14.28 Take 14,
 P(3X7) = p(21) = 500/21 = 23.8  Take 23,
 P(3X5x7) = p(105 ) = 500/105 = 4.76  Take 4


 Answer = 166+100+71-33-14-23+4 = 271
```

I am trying to build the Java code using this C++ implementation https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inclusion-exclusion-principle-and-programming-applications/

```
 int count(int a[], int m, int n)
{
    int odd = 0, even = 0;
    int counter, i, j, p = 1;
    int pow_set_size = (1 << n);


   //this for loop will run 2^n time   
    for (counter = 1; counter < pow_set_size; counter++) {

    //I am not understanding  below for loop code
        p = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            /* Check if jth bit in the counter is set
             If set then pront jth element from set */
            if (counter & (1 << j)) {
                p *= a[j];
            }
        }

        // if set bits is odd, then add to
        // the number of multiples
        if (__builtin_popcount(counter) & 1)
            odd += (100 / p);
        else
            even += 100 / p;
    }

    return odd - even;
}
```

I am just not getting what this for loop really does

```
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {

        /* Check if jth bit in the counter is set
         If set then pront jth element from set */
        if (counter & (1 << j)) {
            p *= a[j];
        }
    }
```

and this part

```
// if set bits is odd, then add to
        // the number of multiples
        if (__builtin_popcount(counter) & 1)
            odd += (100 / p);
        else
            even += 100 / p;
```

given explanation which I am not understanding

> The numbers that are formed by multiplication of an odd number of
>   prime numbers will be added and the numbers  formed by multiplication
>   of even numbers will thus be subtracted to get the total number of
>   multiples in the range 1 to M.

Please can some one help me with this logic to implemnt it in java?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer loop is used to generate all possible sub-sets of prime factors from the input array. Each bit in `counter` represents a position in the array.

The inner loop checks each bit in `counter`, if the bit is set it multiplies the corresponding prime from the array into `p`, the product of all prime factors for the subset being checked. For example, given the array of primes `{3, 5, 7}`:

```
counter bits factors            product
1       001  a[0]               3
2       010  a[1]               5
3       011  a[0] * a[1]        15
4       100  a[2]               7
5       101  a[0] * a[2]        21
6       110  a[1] * a[2]        35
7       111  a[0] * a[1] * a[2] 105
```

The C++ builtin `__builtin_popcount(counter)` counts the number of set bits in `counter`. The Java equivalent is `Integer.bitCount()`. It's used to test if the number of factors in included in `p` is odd (if it is, then the low bit of the result will be set... this could be checked in other ways, e.g. `if (Integer.bitCount(counter) % 2 == 1)`).

Finally, the number of multiples of `p` less than `m` (500 in your case) is calculated, and added to the inclusion set if the number of factors in `p` is odd, or the exclusion set if it is even.

Note that there's a bug in the C++ example, it ignores the `m` parameter and uses the hard-coded value `100`.

In Java:

```
public class IncExc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {3, 5, 7};
        int m = 500;
        System.out.println(count(a, m));
    }

    static int count(int a[], int m) {
        int odd = 0;
        int even = 0;
        int powSetSize = 1 << a.length;

        // For all sub-sets of elements in the array of primes
        for (int counter = 1; counter < powSetSize; counter++) {
            int p = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                // If the jth bit of this combination is set then multiply in the jth element
                if ((counter & (1 << j)) != 0) {
                    p *= a[j];
                }
            }

            // If the number of factors in p is odd, accumulate the count of multiples in our "odd" register
            // Otherwise use the "even" register
            if ((Integer.bitCount(counter) & 1) == 1)
                odd += m / p;
            else
                even += m / p;
        }

        return odd - even;
    }
}
```

Comment: "if the number of factors in included in p is odd (if it is, then the low bit of the result will be set..what does it mean ?" does it mean let say p=21 then 7*3 ,so we have even factors and p=105 then we have 3*7*5 ,which is odd. But 1 is also a factor ? and what does low bit is also set mean ?

Comment: Factor was a poor choice of words sorry. I meant the number of primes taken from the input array and multiplied together. 1 doesn't count.

Comment: The "low bit" is the least significant binary digit of a number. It is always 1 (i.e "set") in odd numbers.

Comment: fine but I have a doubt.when counter is 5 and p is 21,it is going to even variable. Now counter have 101, even number of set bit and 3*7 ,two primes from array(it is also even) does these two things are connected ?

Comment: That's right. The number of bits set in "counter" is the number of primes chosen for the iteration. If the size of the set is odd the result is included.

Comment: Thanks lot @teppic